# Make Visual Studio open tool window floating

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I like to display the results of the right-click > "Find All References" command of Visual Studio 2017 in a floating window and close the window when I'm done. However, every time I close the "references" window and then invoke "Find All References" again, the results are again docked to the bottom of the IDE. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works by default with Visual Studio 2019.

With visual Studio 2017 15.9.12 the behavior is like you describe and I see no way to change this.